# ajax returning php/javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I was playing around with AJAX.

If I do

```
echo "helllo"
```

in the PHP file it works fine.

However, if I do something like

```
echo "<script language=Javascript> alert('hi');</script>";
```

in the PHP file, the `alert()` does not come up.

Anyone know if I'm doing anything wrong?

example:

in my html file i've got this

```
<div id='something'> </div>
```

and i want the response text from the php file be placed above:

```
if (req.status==200) {
     document.getElementById('something').innerHTML=req.responseText;
}
```

if i changed that to:

```
if (req.status==200) {
     document.getElementById('something').innerHTML="<?php echo 'hi';?>";
}
```

it works fine, the response text will be ---> hi
but if i do   `echo "\"<?php echo 'hi';?>\"";`  in my php file,
the response text will be  ""

i hope i was clear in explaining

Answer (score 1):

use [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) , and the script will be evaluated.

```
$("#something").load("request.php");
```

Maybe jQuery there also  uses eval() , so it is'nt more safe, but as long as load() only works on the same Domain u should have Control over the things that will be evaluated.

However, it is easier to use, because you did'nt have to parse the Fragment for script's on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

another approach: using eval

```
var result = ajaxResponseText;// "alert('hi')"; in your case
eval(result);
```

Comment: i answered this when Sunny didn't post this code. how do i know ? just providing another way to play around with javascript. i don't see what wrong with exploring new thing

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote each and every answer that contains the word `eval`. OK, `eval` can be dangerous but 1) it does work 2) there no 100% safe way to do what the OP is asking (this is as good -or as bad- as adding a script tag for instance) 3) if you have the control of what the PHP returns then there is not very much to worry about

Answer (score 0):

You must create script tag with returned data;

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
stript.innerHTML = req.responseText;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```